# Detect copy events properly

Tags: linux, python, clipboard

There's this program called [clipnotify](https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify) which basically all it does is exit on a copy event, so you can use it in while loops. So I have this loop:

```py
while True:
  # clipnotify exits on a copy event
  original = os.popen("xclip -o -sel clip").read()
  os.popen("clipnotify").read()
  content = os.popen("xclip -o -sel clip").read()
  print(content)
  # Ignore alt clipboard event
  if content != original:
    get_items()
    add_item(content)
```

The problem is that clipnotify will exit on a normal copy event like ctrl+c but also on the dreaded selection/highlight copy. I only want from the normal clipboard. So what I do is check if the original changed, and then perform actions. This works except if I want to copy something twice. There's a use case in this program where copying something twice would make sense but it won't get triggered since the `original` variable trick won't make it detect the change.

Kind of a code question of what I could do with the variables to fix this.

But also wondering if there's some other system component I could use that would make this easier.

What I did before was ship with a patched clipnotify.c but now I'm depending on the package.

Comment: Wouldn’t the best solution be to get [this patch](https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify/pull/7) merged?

Comment: Ended up making a package based on that patch.